# the List<> being empty after filling it in for loop

Tags: android, list, for-loop

I want to get details from my DB, and put them in List.
- inside the loop I can see that the List gets the details (list size increases and the values in the list are true.
- after the loop ends, I check the list and find its size is as I want, but the fields values is null!!
the List variable is defined outside the function (i.e it's class field).
 see: 
 Loop Start
  get cursors value
  put value in the List
  check the list value : value is ok.
 Loop End.

### check the list value : value is null.

here is the code:

```
  List<Bundle> friends = new ArrayList<Bundle>();
public  List<Bundle> getAllFriends()
{
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    String Check="Select *  From Friends";
    Cursor c = null;

    String name ="";
    String ID ="";
    String OnlineStt ="";
    String photoUrl ="";
    String friendSince ="";
    Bundle det=new Bundle();
    if(db!=null)
        c=db.rawQuery(Check,null);
    if(c!=null)
    if(c.isBeforeFirst()&&c.getCount()>0) // if there is result/s
    {
        c.moveToFirst();
       do
        {                
             name = c.getString(0);
             ID = c.getString(1);
             OnlineStt = c.getString(2);
             photoUrl = c.getString(3);
             friendSince = c.getString(4);

            det.putString("name",name);// fill the bundle
            det.putString("ID",ID);
            det.putString("OnlineStt",OnlineStt);
            det.putString("photoUrl",photoUrl);
            det.putString("friendSince",friendSince);

            friends.add(det);// put the Bundle in the list
   Log.d("AddFriend---","name in the list: "+friends.get(friends.size()-1).getString("name")); // get true value

            Log.d("AddFriend---","List size="+friends.size()); // size increased // another log.d showed me the current value
            det.clear(); // clear the Bundle

        } while(c.moveToNext());
        if(friends.size()<1)
        { Log.d("FUN","no Friends found!") ;
            return null;}
       } else return null;
for (int x=0;x<friends.size()-1;x++)

Log.d("AddFriend---","name of friend in list: "+friends.get(x).getString("name")); // I get null

Log.d("AddFriend---"," list Size after the loop end "+friends.size()); // I get the true size

return friends;
```

....
Logs results:

```
 AddFriend---﹕ name of friend in list: John
D/AddFriend---﹕ List size=1
D/AddFriend---﹕ name of friend in list: Fadi
---- after the loop:
D/AddFriend---﹕ List size=2
D/AddFriend---﹕ name of friend in list: null
D/AddFriend---﹕ list Size after the loop end 2
```

Comment: `det.clear(); // clear the Bundle` ... every item in this List it is the same instance of Bundle ... so what you expected ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should not call

```
det.clear();
```

but you should create a new instance (`Bundle det = new Bundle()`) at every iteration